# Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

For example:

```
d=['a','b','c','d']
e=['1','2','3','4']
f=['e','f','g','h']
```

I am wondering how to output the following dataframe:

```
a b c d
1 2 3 4
e f g h
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific about your desired outcome? What is the index and what are the column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass in the lists as rows into the DataFrame constructor

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data=[d,e,f])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data=[]
data.append(d)
data.append(e)
data.append(f)
data=pd.DataFrame(data)
print (data)
```